# Android studio: inflating an action bar and ViewGroup parameter

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-viewgroup

I have the following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
if (mActionBar != null) {
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_search, null,false);
```

about the **null** (second parameter of inflate) I get: Avoid passing **null** as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element). I read that it is OK to pass null but I admit that I like to keep my code as clean as possible.

When inflating a `fragment`, I have the container but I didn't find what to pass here in order to avoid this warning.

Please advice
Thanks

Comment: Where do you add 'mCustomView' view? You can pass 'mCustomView's parent view and it will automaticly add to its parent. By that you will keep 'R.layout.action_bar_search' layoutparams options.

Comment: What do you mean where do I add 'mCustomView'? it's in the code I posted.